# How to upgrade webpack 5 when using Angular 13 for Electron app?

Tags: angular, webpack, electron, webpack-5

I am building an Electron app and use Angular **v11** and webpack **v4**.

I want to upgrade both to Angular **v13** and webpack **v5**. Most upgrade guides refer to common web apps, but given the Electron foundation, I am running into some unexpected issues.

My current problem is this error message:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
        - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
```

According to several guides, there are several locations where I have to adjust my settings, but none of them work. Can anyone point out to me which are the correct changes, and which one I can ignore or revert?

## angular.json

```
allowedCommonJsDependencies: [
// add crypto, os, ...
"crypto", "os", ...
]
```

## tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths" : {
      "crypto": ["./node_modules/crypto-browserify"],
      "stream": ["./node_modules/stream-browserify"],
      "assert": ["./node_modules/assert"],
      "http": ["./node_modules/stream-http"],
      "https": ["./node_modules/https-browserify"],
      "os": ["./node_modules/os-browserify"],
    },
```

## webpack.config.js

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],// other stuff
    fallback: {
      crypto: "crypto-browserify",
      http: "stream-http",
      https: "https-browserify",
      os: "os-browserify/browser",
      path: "path-browserify",
      stream: "stream-browserify",
      process: "process/browser",
      url: "url/",
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Run `npm install stream-browserify`.

2.Add a path mapping in `tsconfig.json`:

```
...
"compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
    "stream": [ "./node_modules/stream-browserify" ]
  },
}
```

3.Add stream to `allowedCommonJsDependencies` in `angular.json`:

```
"options": {
  "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
    "angular-slickgrid", "stream"
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is `stream` just an example for all other modules that type?

Comment: `stream` is a polyfill that was previously included with WebPack 4 and is no longer included with WebPack 5 but you can simply reinstall it by following the  steps shown in this answer, which are the same steps shown in my lib [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid#angular-12-with-webpack-5---how-to-fix-polyfill-error), so this answer is probably valid since my lib is working with Angular 13 following these instructions, however I can't answer for Electron since I never used it